# How can I get this sort of effect on my photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I'm looking to get this sort of effect on my photo with the vintage type look with a red coloured highlight, I'm using photoshop & have tried using `threshold color` but the look doesn't come out very similar. Specifically the highlights don't look great. Does anyone know a good way to reproduce something like this in photoshop? Or the techniques they are using to do this?

[image]

Comment: I believe what makes you like this image isn't just *one* effect. The coloring can be easily achieved by using a *Gradient Map* (search for it on this site). But just applying that to any image won't make it look like this. It's a collage of different elements which have been melted together by manipulating the photos to look a bit like a drawing and adding different kinds of texture and noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to get something similar to the human figures, and that you have already removed any background. So here's one method to get something similar.

Here's the image I used
[image]

1. Turn your image layer into a Smart Object, and do *Filters > Camera RAW*, and use settings similar to those shown below. The idea here is to try to add extra contrast to the image to make it look a bit like an illustration.

[image]

2. Next, sample the colours of your original example to create a gradient something like this

[image]

3. Do *Filter > Artistic > Poster Edges*, with settings as shown

[image]

4. Do *Filter > Sharpen > Smart Sharpen*, with settings as shown

[image]

5. Apply the gradient you made previously as a Gradient Map adjustment Layer

Here's the finished result. I added some gradients as a background. Note all the filters and adjustments here are non-destructive, so you can edit and tweak everything until you get the desired effect.

[image]

Comment: My hero lol, Thank you!